# How can I make a Swift HTTP POST hit a Flask server?

Tags: python, ios, rest, swift

I am trying to post some data to a Flask server, whose code is the following:

```
@app.route('/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)

    task = {
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json.get('description', ""),
    }

    return jsonify({'task' : task}), 201
```

When I run this, it works fine, and I can make POST requests successfully using curl, with the expected behavior on the back end above and the expected return value in command line. I want to make a post to this server using Swift, however, and am having trouble with that. I have followed the tutorial detailing this behavior [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/). In particular, I put the code in my `AppDelegate.swift` so it is executed as soon as the app launches. The full code is in the link posted, but for reference I am also posting it below:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:4567/login"))
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params = ["username":"jameson", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")
        var err: NSError?
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
        if(err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
         }
         else {
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still
            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.
            if let parseJSON = json {
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                println("Succes: \(success)")
            }
            else {
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        }
    })

    task.resume()
    return true
}
```

However, when I launch this app, I have the following logged in my xcode

```
Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc4dae218a0> { URL: http://localhost:5000/task } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 26;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Oct 2014 19:22:57 GMT";
    Server = "Werkzeug/0.9.6 Python/2.7.5";
} }
Body: {
  "error": "Not found"
}
Succes: nil
```

I've been working with this and tinkering with the input, it seems that the back end is fine, but I'm wondering what is wrong with this front end, unfortunately Swift documentation is for the moment fairly moot on this point and seems to be the only solution floating around for RESTful API calls at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flask route is `'/tasks'` and you're trying to post to `http://localhost:5000/task`. Is that a typo, or are you a victim of failure to pluralize?

Comment: Happens to everybody. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to do better error handling with better messages in the response.